# Bounded Queue Overhead

Tags: java, queue

I'm having trouble answering the following question, I've included my answers below. Can someone tell me where I'm going wrong? Thanks!

Assume that an integer requires 2 bytes of space and a reference requires 4 bytes of space. Also assume the maximum queue size is 200.

How much overhead space (in bytes) is needed, assuming a queue that holds ints, for:

```
The text's bounded array-based queue holding 20 elements? My Answer: 840
The text's bounded array-based queue holding 100 elements? My Answer: 1000
The text's bounded array-based queue holding 200 elements? My Answer: 1200
The text's reference-based queue holding 20 elements? My Answer: 80
The text's reference-based queue holding 100 elements? My Answer: 400
The text's reference-based queue holding 200 elements? My Answer: 800
```

Finally, for what size queue do the array-based and reference-based approaches use approximately the same amount of overhead space? My answer: Queue of 200 elements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) int is 4 bytes, but collections dont work with primitives, so int in a queue will be represented with Integer which is an object, 1 Integer occupies 16 bytes.

2) it depends on queue implementation, in case of a linked queue each element will be associated with a link consisting of 2 - 3 references, each link will occupy 30+ bytes

3) read http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/memory/object_memory_usage.shtml

Comment: I'm not sure I follow, could you explain that another way?

Comment: The parameters of the question are unrealistic , I know, but they do still apply...

Comment: Main point is that an Object in java is at least 8 bytes. Integer size is 16 bytes, it is described here http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/memory/object_memory_usage.shtml

Answer (score 1):

Explanation from my professor:
Because the Queue ADT in the textbook holds generic type elements, each element in the queue stores a reference to an object (of types like Integer, Double, String, etc. They are all reference types (wrapper classes) rather than primitive types). Therefore, for the array-based Queue with Integer as the element type, each array slot holds a reference to an Integer object. Since the array-based implementation has a fixed-size underlying array, it has to preallocate memory for the array when a queue is created. The total memory space required is (size of array (same as # of references)) x (4 bytes) + (# of Integer objects) x (2 bytes).

As far as the reference-based Integer Queue, each element is a linked-list node, which has two fields: a reference to an Integer object and a reference to the next node in the linked list. In other words, each node has two references. Therefore, the total memory space required is (# of nodes (same as # of Integer objects)) x 2 x (4 bytes) + (# of Integer objects) x (2 bytes).